# WinForms not drawing ProgressBar according to its properties

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I'm using a `ProgressBar` to monitor the population of a `DataGridView` with data retrieved from a database, alongside a `Label` placed on its left.

There's nothing fancy about this. Data retrieval takes place in the `DoWork` handler of a `BackgroundWorker` and in this time the `ProgressBar` is in Marquee style while the `Label` displays a generic 'Loading...'. Once the loading is complete, the `ProgressChanged` handler of the `BackgroundWorker` adds rows to the `DataGridView` one by one, while the `ProgressBar` and `Label` display the progress. The code I'm using for this is below:

```
*code that adds row*
if (e.ProgressPercentage > 0)
    pbrProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage - 1;
pbrProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
lblProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "/" + pbrProgress.Maximum;
```

The `Label` always displays correctly, and by debugging I discovered that the `ProgressBar` has the right `Value` and `Maximum` properties as well. However, the `ProgressBar` doesn't actually begin to show progress (the green filling) until it reaches the 10th result or so. It is also pretty far from being full when the last result is added to the `DataGridView`.

Images:
[Beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS3Jb.png)
[Near the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZbeU.png)

I've tried adding `pbrProgress.Refresh();` at the end of the code, and also using a custom `ProgressBar` with the `DoubleBuffered` property set to `true`, to no avail.

Really, the only solution I've found is having the thread sleep for 80ms after each call of `ReportProgress`. Is there a better way than that?

Comment: [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the solution was incredibly simple.

Instead of

```
if (e.ProgressPercentage > 0)
    pbrProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage - 1;
pbrProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

it had to be

```
pbrProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
if (e.ProgressPercentage > 0)
      pbrProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage - 1;
```

I have no idea why it works one way and not the other. Perhaps because the progressbar value only changes once on the first iteration?

Regardless, this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that the progressbar is not responding and so its not redrawing itself.

Such work-intense stuff should be called in the `DoWork`-Event of a `BackgroundWorker` and not in the `ProgressChanged`-Event.
The `ProgressChanged`-Event is the place where you want to change your `ProgressBar`.

So you could do sth. like this:

```
private static void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int size = 100;

            // Function to Setup your Progressbar
            form.SetUpProgressBar(size);

            // hard work...
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                // Fires the Worker_ProgressChanged Event with the Percentage of the current progress
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i + 1);
            }
        }

        private static void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the ProgressBar
            form.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private static void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hey I'm done!");
        }
```

**Note:**

Before you can use `worker.ReportProgress()` you have to call `worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;`, otherwise you will run into an error.

The Method call inside `ProgressChanged` needs Invocation (hit me up, if you don't know how to do this).

You should use BackgroundWorker like this:

1) `DoWork` for your heavy work that has to be seperated from the GUI Thread 
2) `ProgressChanged` to report Progress to your ProgressBar 
3) `RunWorkerComplete` to indicate that you are now done (close Windows etc.)

You can feed the BackgroundWorker some values to work with like this: `worker.RunWorkerAsync(value);` and access this via `(e.Argument as int)` (or whatever) in the `DoWork`-Event.

Hope this helps :)

-- Maddin

Answer (score -1):

Simple: Add an `Application.Doevents()` after you set the `Value` property of the `ProgressBar`.

Comment: I've just tried it, but it doesn't seem to help in any noticeable way.

Comment: OK, try settng teh double buffer to true on your form, and do an invalidate on the progressbar.  Also make sure you are checking if invoke is required.